# Directory permissions are not set in the Docker Compose(Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My service(`docker-compose.yml`):

```
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: configs/nodejs
      args:
        - UID=$UID
        - GID=$GID
    container_name: nodejs_container
    volumes:
      - ${APP_HOST}:${APP_CONTAINER_PATH}
    working_dir: ${APP_CONTAINER_FRONTEND_PATH}
    command: sh -c "ls -la && npm install && npm run build"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ARG UID
ARG GID
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
USER $UID:$GID
```

But the rights to the files are not set correctly

```
nodejs_container | total 728
nodejs_container | drwxrwxr-x    4 1001     xfs           4096 Jan 26 07:09 .
nodejs_container | drwxrwxr-x   15 1001     xfs           4096 Jan 26 06:06 ..
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs             43 Jan 24 16:47 .browserslistrc
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs            121 Jan 24 16:47 .editorconfig
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs           3302 Jan 24 16:47 .eslintrc.js
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs            283 Jan 24 16:47 .gitignore
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs            427 Jan 24 16:47 README.md
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs             76 Jan 24 16:47 babel.config.js
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs             50 Jan 24 16:47 cypress.json
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs            834 Jan 24 16:47 jest.config.js
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs         680479 Jan 26 06:54 package-lock.json
nodejs_container | -rw-rw-r--    1 1001     xfs           2048 Jan 25 09:26 package.json
...
```

Before starting docker, I set my environment variables: `export UID=$(id -u)` and `export GID=$(id -g)`

Why wasn't the `$UID:$GID` value set for directories and files from the environment variables in which docker compose was run?

Answer (score 0):

Try ***environment*** key word instead if ***args***

As an example,

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: It doesn't work either. .env output (cat .env): `UID = 1001 GID = 33`

Answer (score 0):

When you mount `volumes:` on to a container on a native-Linux host, the numeric file owner and permissions from the host system are used as-is in the container.  If host user ID 1001 owns the files then inside the container they will also be owned by ID 1001.  The user ID of the container doesn't come into play here.

In principle you could use an entrypoint wrapper script to change the owner of the files, but this would also change their owner on the host.  Better practice would be to move all of the setup you currently have into the Dockerfile: `COPY` the application code in, `RUN npm ci && npm build`, and then set the `CMD` of the container to launch the application.  The specific user ID this isolated container runs as won't matter, though it's good practice to not be root.

Given the Dockerfile and Compose setup you show, it may be more efficient to just use a host Node process.  That will naturally run using the host's filesystem and the host user ID.  That's doubly true if you're just trying to use this setup as a build system for your local files.